# likelihood of a nominal distribution given hypothesized probabilities

Tags: likelihood, categorical-data

I have a number of hypotheses which state the probability of observing each possible datum. For example, one hypothesis might set the `p` of observing `A` at 0.1, `B` at 0.3, and `C` at 0.6. Let's say that I then observe 4 `A`s, 4 `B`s, and 1 `C`. Given this hypothesis, what is the likelihood of observing this distribution?

A friend suggested that I use the KL-divergence of the two ``distributions'', but the output of KL-divergence is not a probability (it's bits), so I do not believe that it is interpretable as a likelihood.

How can I calculate the likelihood of having observed a distribution, given a hypothesized probability distribution?

Comment: The likelihood ratio test between two known distributions $P$ and $Q$ (which is optimal in the Neyman-Pearson sense) can be written as $D(\hat{p} || P) - D(\hat{p} || Q) $ compared to some threshold $\tau$ where $\hat{p}$ being the empirical distribution of the data.  You can also relate it to generalized likelihood ratio tests (e.g. Hoeffding 65). In your case though, it simply sounds like you need to write down Bayes rule for your situation and apply it.

Comment: @Batman The likelihood of observing the data given the hypothesis is part of the Bayesian inference. You've said how this can be written, but how can it be calculated?

Comment: When you say "likelihood" are you really asking about *likelihood* (in the technical-jargon sense) or do you just mean in the ordinary-English sense "probability"? I'm presuming you mean likelihood in the technical sense (as in a likelihood function) but I just want to make sure.

Comment: My answer should have you covered either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of observing $n_A$ $A$s, $n_B$ $B$s, and $n_C$ $C$'s under independent draws from a distribution over those categories with
given probabilities $p_A$, $p_B$ and $p_C$ which sum to $1$ is

$${N\choose {\,n_{_A}\, n_{_B}\, n_{_C}\,}}\,p_{_A}^{n_A}\, p_{_B}^{n_B}\, p_{_C}^{n_C}$$

where $N=n_A +n_B+ n_C$ and ${N\choose {n_{_A}\, n_{_B}\, n_{_C}}}=\frac{N!}{n_A!\, n_B!\, n_C!}$.

The general case with $k$ categories of outcome is called the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), of which the binomial is a special case (as is this trinomial).

The *likelihood*, $\mathcal{L}(p_{_A},p_{_B},p_{_C}|n_{_A},n_{_B},n_{_C})$ is equal to the above probability of $(n_{_A},n_{_B},n_{_C})$ given the set of category probabilities $(p_{_A},p_{_B},p_{_C})$.

Comment: I'm running into problems computing this in python because for large numbers, $N!$ is a VERY large number. Do you know if there a sneaky way to compute this without actually computing the factorial?

Comment: Compute the entire calculation on the log-scale (you'll want a log-gamma function). What are you working in?

Comment: I am working in python. See my "answer" for code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Glen_b can be implemented in `python` as follows.

```
from math import e, lgamma, log

def mlt_prob_log(p_dict, d_dict):  # multinomial distribution
    """Return log-likelihood of observing d_dict assuming p_dict."""
    return ((lgamma(sum(d_dict.values()) + 1) -
            (sum([lgamma(i + 1) for i in d_dict.values()]))) +
            (sum([log(p) * d_dict.get(e, 0) for e, p in p_dict.items()])))
```

Comment: I'd advise leaving it as a log-likelihood unless you definitely need a likelihood. Almost everything of value people do with likelihoods can be done with the logs, and there's a far lower risk of underflow (or in some situations overflow) with the logs when dealing with large samples. What are you using the likelihood to do?